# Doubt about the expression of the work done during a quasi-static isothermal change of a paramagnetic substance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I want to prove that the work during a quasi-static ishothermal change of state of a paramagnetic substance obeying Curi'es law is given by:

$W_T=-\cfrac{T}{C}\left\{\cfrac{1}{2}M_f^2-\cfrac{1}{2}M_i^2\right\}=-\cfrac{T}{C}\left\{\cfrac{1}{2}H_f^2-\cfrac{1}{2}H_i^2\right\}$

My try:

Since the work done on a paramagnetic substance is given by $dW=\mu_0Hdm$, integrating

$W=\mu_0\int_{m_i}^{m_f}Hdm=\mu_0 \int_{m_i}^{m_f}\cfrac{m}{\lambda}dm$ with $\lambda$ the
magnetic susceptibility and since $\lambda=\cfrac{C}{T}$

$W=\mu_0\int_{m_i}^{m_f}\cfrac{m}{{\cfrac{C}{T}}}dm=\mu_0\int_{m_i}^{m_f}\cfrac{mT}{C}dm=\cfrac{\mu_0 T}{C}\int_{m_i}^{m_f}mdm=\cfrac{\mu_0 T}{C}\left[\cfrac{1}{2}m^2\right]_{m_i}^{m_f}=\cfrac{\mu_0 T}{C}\left[\cfrac{1}{2}m_f^2-\cfrac{1}{2}m_i^2\right]$

And again using Curie's Law: $M_{i(f)}=\cfrac{C H_{i(f)}}{T}$ I get:

$W=\cfrac{\mu_0 T}{C}\left[\cfrac{1}{2}m_f^2-\cfrac{1}{2}m_i^2\right]=\cfrac{\mu_0 T}{C}\left[\cfrac{1}{2}\cfrac{C^2H_f^2}{T^2}-\cfrac{1}{2}\cfrac{C^2H_f^2}{T^2}\right]=\cfrac{\mu_0 T}{C}\cdot\cfrac{C^2}{T^2}\left[ \cfrac{1}{2}H_f^2-\cfrac{1}{2}H_i^2\right]=\cfrac{\mu_0 C}{T}\left[ \cfrac{1}{2}H_f^2-\cfrac{1}{2}H_i^2\right]$

$W=\cfrac{\mu_0 T}{C}\left[\cfrac{1}{2}m_f^2-\cfrac{1}{2}m_i^2\right]=\cfrac{\mu_0 C}{T}\left[ \cfrac{1}{2}H_f^2-\cfrac{1}{2}H_i^2\right]$

But my question is: where does the negative sign they are asking me come from? Or can I assume that $\mu_0=-1$ .
Since in case of being like this the demonstration would be done. I appreciate your help

Comment: Your $W$ is correct (don't even think of a negative $\mu_o$ because it is a defined quantity in EM to be $+4\pi \times 10^{-7}$). The negative sign in $W_T$ could be a typo or it might mean the work done *by* the paramagnetic substance *on* the battery that is supplying the bias current.